# Codeigniter 2 Controller Fall Through to a different controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a site I am working on that has a URL structure that looks like:

```
example.com/category-name
```

This currently goes to a 1000 line long controller called pages that was built years ago and has never been changed. I am inserting a new controller above this in the route that looks like:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'new_controller/load/$1
$route['default_controller'] = "pages";
```

The idea is for `new_controller` to work like this:

```
example.com/page-name
```

This looks up `page-name` in a database and displays some text made by business people in the admin of the site.

The problem comes from that if `page-name` is not found in this table, for legacy purposes I must fall through `new_controller/load` and then use the pages controller normally.

For SEO reasons I can't change the URL structure, it has to remain `example.com/category-name` and they want it to share the same URL structure `example.com/page-name` because it's shorter(I tried to convince them to do something like `example.com/page/page-name`)

From `new_controller/load/$1` how would I then call say `pages/view/$1` ?

Thanks in advance it is going to really save my butt at work haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `route config` you can use the config below. new_controller controller handles all page requests so long as their uris don't contain `pages/view/.*` which `pages` controller handles.

```
$route['pages\/view\/(.*)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['(?!pages\/view)(.*)'] = 'new_controller/load/$1';
```

In `new_controller` controller - you can do something like the code below so if the slug doesn't exist in database it will be handled by `pages` controller instead.

```
public function load($slug)
{
        if(/*slug in database*/){
            echo "Slug content from database";
        }
        else { // slug not in database

            redirect(site_url('pages/view/'.$slug)); // You can use this
            echo file_get_contents(site_url('pages/view/'.$slug)); // or this
            $this->load->view('pages_template'); // or this
            // or semething else.
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm worried about the redirect being an SEO issue if it sees a redirect every time it doesn't match in the new controller it could potentially hurt SEO, the other ones are interesting I will try them and see what happens.

Comment: For those who are reading this later, I basically went with the above answer but instead of an if/else I used a switch/case due to other non database driven routes being needed.